# .Net regex giving different results than expected

Tags: .net, regex

My regex expression:

```
(1|0|0[\.,]\d+)\((\d+|\d+[\.,]\d+)\)
```

The string I'm trying to parse:

```
1(1)0(19)0.5(0.2)0(10)0.3(1,9)

Expected matches:

 Match 1: '1'   '1'   
 Match 2: '0'   '19'   
 Match 3: '0.5' '0.2'   
 Match 4: '0'   '10'   
 Match 5: '0.3' '1.9'
```

For some reason the last match is `'0.3' '19'` unless I use 0.3(1.9) instead of 0.3(1,9). So I'm assuming something is up with the ',' vs '.', but I thought my regex expr. would account for that?

I matched my string against the expression using the following sites:

http://www.regexr.com/  matches fine
https://regex101.com/r/uE4vU9/3 matches fine
http://regexpal.com/ matches fine
http://regexhero.net/tester/  matches fine

Comment: For `regex101` link, you need the `g` flag. https://regex101.com/r/uE4vU9/2

Comment: @hjpotter92 ty, still the problem is the same, the online tools all parse (1,9) fine, but the .net parses gives back 19 instead of 1.9

Comment: Just tested in PowerShell: works, final group of final match is `"1,9"`. Could you show the code you are using to perform the matching: ie. enough that we can compile and run to get the same result. (I have a theory, but want to be able to check it.)

Comment: @Richard found the problem, i'll post it below, it wasn't the regex.

Comment: My theory: you were parsing the matched value as a number and then converting back to a string. but in a different (possibly implicit) locale. Edit: now I've seen the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the code I was running:

```
 Public Function ParsePulseTrain(input As String) As List(Of Pulse)
    Dim _regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(1|0|0[\.,]\d+)\((\d+|\d+[\.,]\d+)\)")
    Dim pulsetrain As New List(Of Pulse)
    If _regex.IsMatch(input) Then
        Dim matches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = _regex.Matches(input)
        For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In matches
            pulsetrain.Add(New Pulse(Single.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Single.Parse(m.Groups(2).Value, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        Next
    End If
    Return pulsetrain
End Function
```

As you can see, when parsing the m.groups values I was using invariantculture info which is using '.' for the decimal places. Hence the problem.